# What thread-safe data persistence objects are available in Python for data persistence?

Tags: python, thread-safety, persistence

What Python thread-safe data persistence objects are available for data persistence? I need something that's similar to shelve. It's best if I can just change only a little bit of code instead of re-writing all parts related to data persistence.

I Googled about this a bit but didn't find too much useful information.

Comment: Persisting where?  Flat files?  Databases?

Comment: I want something that's similar to shelve that is thread-safe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the ZODB providing native object persistence:

http://www.zodb.org/